# Perché ci sono tante interiezioni che contengono la "h"?

Tags: orthography, history, interjections

Perché l'italiano, una lingua con pochissime "h" (eccetto dopo "c" e "g" e alcune forme del verbo avere), ha tante interiezioni che contengono la "h" nella loro grafia?

Ecco alcuni esempi:

> *Ah! Ahi! Ahimè! Ahó! Oh! Ohe! Ohi! Ohimè! Eh! Bah! Boh! Beh! Ehi! Ehm! Uh! Uhm! Mah! Ih!*

Answer (score 4):

Quelle *h* spesso modificano le vocali in un qualche modo, es. con suoni aspirati oppure allungandole. Nelle altre parole è raro che ci siano queste cose.

L'unico caso di parola quasi "normale" con la *h* usata in quel modo che mi viene in mente è *vabbè* (*va bene* -> *vabbene* -> *vabbe(ne)* -> *vabbè*) che si può scrivere correttamente anche come *va beh*. 
Cosa cambia? Come lo dico io (accento lombardo) è con la h e senza la doppia b (il raddoppio a nord non si fa), quindi scrivo *va beh*.

Comunque quando la gente le scrive (sempre in chat perché a meno che scrivi novelle non le usi, e quindi senza fare attenzione all'ortografia corretta ma basandosi sulla propria pronuncia) tende a scriverle in modi diversi o "sbagliati" perché sono un po' ambigue secondo me, soprattutto se non se ne conosce l'origine.

Answer (score 3):

Domanda molto interessante. Azzardo una possibile spiegazione (che meriterebbe forse di essere un commento più che una risposta).

La `h`, anche in parole straniere, perlopiù in italiano non viene pronunciata. Mi sembra che talvolta venga usata per rendere nella scrittura di queste interiezioni un 'allungamento' della vocale a cui si attacca, più che un suono consonantico. È un uso molto simile a quello che assume nel francese moderno.

Comment: Puoi chiarire il parallelo col francese, magari con un esempio?

Answer (score 2):

Credo sia semplicemente un tentativo di riprodurre la pronuncia: quando dici "oh!" "Beh!" "Ahi!" espiri, ossia mandi fuori l'aria dalla bocca, in modo più prolungato ed evidente che nelle normali conversazioni.